# why does SVM outperforms KNN in 1-gram but in 2,3,4, and 5 KNN outperforms SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, unbalanced-classes, accuracy, k-nearest-neighbour

my project is authorship attribution which is a multiclass classification, the number of classes is 150, and the number of documents is 2798; it is also an unbalanced issue some classes have more instances than others, for SVM I used linear kernel and c=2, and for KNN I used k=4. the result was as follows:

SVM:

1-gram: 80

2-gram: 52

3-gram: 26

4-gram: 17

5-gram: 11

KNN:

1-gram: 35

2-gram: 53

3-gram: 44

4-gram: 31

5-gram: 19

note: I used the TF-IDF vectorizer

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Comment: I mean is there any explanation for this situation?